# Read bitmaps and video from a USB camera onto an Android 4.0 device?

Tags: android

Is there support in the Android libraries to do this? If so, where? If not, can you point me at libraries or projects that attack this problem?

I can see there is support in more recent Android releases for USB devices that specifically support Android USB protocols, but I cannot see any mention of whether cameras can simply be plugged in and used in the same way keyboards or mice often can.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/index.html

Comment: Have you seen the reference to MTP/PTP API in http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-3.1.html?